# How to initialize the Windows socket library without admin rights

Tags: .net, windows, sockets, winsock

I'm writing a program that calls the OpenOffice.org API through .NET. The documentation at http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/CLI/Writing_Client_Programs says:

For OOo 3.x the code is this:

```
//C# example for OOo 3.x
//Workaround which is needed when using a socket connection
//This will initialize the Windows socket library.
System.Net.Sockets.Socket s = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(
AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
```

which works fine on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, but on Windows 7 it fails with:

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions

which I understand is because the socket type is raw and the program is not running with admin rights. So my question is: how can I initialize the Windows socket library without admin rights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access to RAW sockets requires admin rights on Windows 2000 and later, and that is described on MSDN:

[TCP/IP Raw Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548.aspx)

> Raw sockets offer the capability to manipulate the underlying transport, so they can be used for malicious purposes that pose a security threat. Therefore, only members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later.
>
> ...
>
> **Note** To use a socket of type SOCK_RAW requires administrative privileges. Users running Winsock applications that use raw sockets must be a member of the Administrators group on the local computer, otherwise raw socket calls will fail with an error code of WSAEACCES. On Windows Vista and later, access for raw sockets is enforced at socket creation. In earlier versions of Windows, access for raw sockets is enforced during other socket operations.

There is no way to get around that restriction.  On the other hand, if your intention is just to initialize Winsock in general, then you do not need to create a RAW socket to do that.  Create a TCP (`SocketType.Stream` and `ProtocolType.TCP`) or UDP (`SocketType.DGram` and `ProtocolType.UDP`) socket instead, which are not restricted, and most likely what OOo is actually going to use internally anyway.  Or, you could use PInvoke to call Winsock's `WSAStartup()` function directly.

Comment: Thanks, SocketType.Stream and ProtocolType.TCP does the trick.